# Finding one of several keys in a matrix

Tags: performance, recursion, matrix

Here is my set of numbers that I'm looking to match against

```
(33, 15, 1)
```

I might have X number of arrays

that look like

```
(15, 1, 7)
(20, 5, 15)
(7, 2, 33) 
 ... 
 ...
```

This combination of arrays essentially represents a matrix right?

These numbers hold significance, **so they shouldn't be sorted** (they are specific ids in a database)

Basically the the solution needs to first go through my first set of numbers one at a time and see if the we get a match in the first column, if not, go to the second column, if not check the third column,

so it would be 33 == 15 -> 33 == 20 -> 33 == 7 -> 33 == 1 -> 33 == 5 ,etc until we find a match, so in this case we match the last number in the last array and this would return.

failing all that, we would move to the second number from my search set (15) and start at the beginning of the matrix and loop through everything again trying to find a match, and so on.

What is the most efficient solution to this problem? At first I was thinking recursion but now I'm not sure. There has to be a better way than looping through each data set over and over again. A simple iteration procedure seems like it would a lot of overhead depending on the size of the number sets.

[EDIT] -

This problem right now is exactly this size, limited to 3 columns

but the number of rows could theoretically grow to a few hundred, these are really rows from the database, as i add more information the number of rows will grow

Comment: An idea of the problem size could help us understand what kind of structures could be advantageous to set  up.

Answer (score 0):

depending on what rows these come from in the database and how structured, an index on those column(s) and a sql query to give you the correct row(s) should be faster than bringing back all 100s of rows into the client for processing.  Also depends on how big the whole database is in comparison to the chuck you care about.  DBMS are generally very good at exactly this and do so with multiple worker threads spanning the whole table collecting rows for you.